# derivation of a gap related to extreme value theory

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

I have an expression to evaluate as follow:

$\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{k=1}^K s_k f(x_k)\Big|s_k=s_k^{\ast} \right]$

where $\{s_k^\ast\}$ can be treated as a ${policy}$ which is defined as follows:

\begin{align}
 {s}_k^\ast=\left\{
  \begin{aligned}
   &1, \quad \text{if } X_k=\max_j \{X_j\}>0 \\
   &0, \quad otherwise
  \end{aligned}\right.
\end{align}
with
\begin{align}
   X_k=a_k\left[\log (a_k x_k) \right]^+ -\Big(a_k-\frac{1}{x_k}\Big)^+
\end{align}
where $a_k>0$ for all $k$ are constants, and $x_k>0$ is a random variable following $\exp(1)$ distribution. Let me define another simple policy:
\begin{align}
 \widetilde{s}_k^\ast=\left\{
  \begin{aligned}
   &1, \quad \text{if } x_k=\max_j \{x_j\} \\
   &0, \quad otherwise
  \end{aligned}\right.
\end{align}

According to the extreme value theory, we know the growth rate result: $x_{k^\ast}=\mathcal{O}(\log K)$, where $k^\ast=\arg\max_k \{x_k\}$, and $K$ is the number of random variables. Based on this result and the definitions of ${s}_k^\ast$ and $\widetilde{s}_k^\ast$, we know that
\begin{align}
    {s}_k^\ast \rightarrow \widetilde{s}_k^\ast, \quad as \ K \rightarrow \infty
\end{align}
Therefore, we must have
\begin{align}
    \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{k=1}^K s_k f(x_k)\Big|s_k=s_k^{\ast} \right] \rightarrow \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{k=1}^K s_k f(x_k)\Big|s_k=\widetilde{s}_k^{\ast} \right], \quad as \ K \rightarrow \infty
\end{align}
My question is whether we can quantify the gap w.r.t. $K$, i.e., 
\begin{align}
    \left|\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{k=1}^K s_k f(x_k)\Big|s_k=s_k^{\ast} \right] -\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{k=1}^K s_k f(x_k)\Big|s_k=\widetilde{s}_k^{\ast} \right]\right|
\end{align}
decrease at what order w.r.t. $K$ as $K$ increases?

Comment: You need conditions on f to guarantee convergence. Please specify them.

Comment: actually, in my case $f(x)=max[1-1/x,0]$.

Comment: OK. But I am confused as to what $s_k$ is, without the asterisk?

Comment: Is the condition in the expectation a set of conditions for all k? In that case the expectation is simply E(f(x_k*)), where k* is the random index that of the largest x. This is just evaluating the expectation of some max of iid exp(1), which is pretty trivial.